# Cant able to update the polyline in the map using react hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, polyline, react-native-maps

Please help me here I am trying to update polyline based on the user tracking but the polyline is not getting updated and i am using the functional components i had tried different ways but its not working. Please help me Below is code i had wrote

Map component

```
<MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={{flex: 1, borderRadius: 20}}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            userLocationPriority={'high'}
            userLocationFastestInterval={2000}
            initialRegion={{
                latitude: originLat,
                longitude: originLng,
                latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                longitudeDelta: 0.01,
            }}>
            <Marker.Animated
                coordinate={
                    new AnimatedRegion({
                        latitude: originLat,
                        longitude: originLng,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    })
                }
                pinColor={'#FF8C00'}>
                <Image
                    source={Images.marker}
                    style={{height: 100, width: 100, marginTop: 36}}
                />
            </Marker.Animated>
            <Polyline
                coordinates={userLocation}
                strokeColor={colors.blue}
                strokeWidth={3}
            />
        </MapView>
```

Watch poistion

```
const watchPosition = () => {
    Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
            const userUpdatedLocation = new Location();
            userUpdatedLocation.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            userUpdatedLocation.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            setUserLocationLL(userUpdatedLocation);
        },
        error => {
            Alert.alert(error.message.toString());
        },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 100,
            maximumAge: 0,
            distanceFilter: 0,
            useSignificantChanges: true
        },
    );
}
```

Below are variables i am assigning

```
const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState<Location[]>([]);
    const [userLocationLL, setUserLocationLL] = useState<Location>(initialLocation);
```

Polyline :

```
   <Polyline
  coordinates={userLocation}
  strokeColor={colors.blue}
  strokeWidth={3}
/>
```

Updating the set state

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUserLocation(locations => [...locations, userLocationLL]);
}, [userLocationLL]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing updating the `userLocation` state holding the historical location data in an array to plot out.

```
<Polyline
  coordinates={userLocation} // <-- array of locations
  strokeColor={colors.blue}
  strokeWidth={3}
/>
```

You can either update the `userLocation` array in the `watchPosition` handler

```
const watchPosition = () => {
  Geolocation.watchPosition(
    position => {
      const userUpdatedLocation = new Location();
      userUpdatedLocation.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      userUpdatedLocation.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      setUserLocationLL(userUpdatedLocation);

      // Append new position to `userLocation` array
      setUserLocation(locations => [...locations, userUpdatedLocation]);
    },
    ....
  );
}
```

or you can use an `useEffect` hook to update the `userLocation` state when the `userLocationLL` state updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUserLocation(locations => [...locations, userLocationLL]);
}, [userLocationLL]);
```

Comment: I am doing that as well @Drew Reese

Comment: Yes i tried that its not working

Comment: @AyubBaba Can you be a little more specific about what isn't working? Is this react-native code? If so can you try creating an [Expo snack](https://expo.io/) with a minimal, reproducible example that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I had tried using the set state as well but the polyline is not getting updated

Comment: Also updated the question

Comment: @AyubBaba Think you could create an [Expo Snack](https://expo.dev/) of your code that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?